# How to preserve line breaks but have text-align:justify?

Tags: html, css

I have text which has line breaks as needed and I don't want to have to add a `<br/>` after each line so I use `white-space: pre-wrap`. I want to have `text-align:justify` as well. But they don't seem to work together.

Is there a way to overcome that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is `white-space:pre-line`, not `pre-wrap`.

And you also need [`text-align-last`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last), because `text-align` by itself won't cut it.

```css
div {
  white-space: pre-line;
  text-align: justify;
  -moz-text-align-last: justify;
  text-align-last: justify;
}
```

```html
<div>one two three four
five six seven etc etc etc</div>
```

Comment: I would think that `text-align-last` should be `left`, but then it's not clear from the OP's question.

Comment: Thanks. `pre-line` was it.

Comment: Ehm... but if you set `text-align-last:left` or don't use `text-align-last` at all, it doesn't justify any of the lines, at least in my browser. Even if you do have `text-align:justify`.

Comment: I just omitted the `text-align-last` completely. (But thanks for that information. It might come in handy some other time.)

Answer (score 0):

You can get text to auto-wrap by using the max-width property in css on the element that contains the text (or any parent element)

```css
p{
 max-width:300px;
 text-align:justify;
}
```

```html
<p>dfhdbh dgg dd ew asdf dhfdhfh d hdhfbk djdbjbk dhdbhfbd jkbfjbdjk hdjkhjkdh dhfjkdhkfjgdfkdj df djfhkdjfh hdfbdh dfdhf fdhgdgds sdh dfhdbvdhg shdgh dfhf dfhdff fhddh fhfgdssdsew dfhgseey dhd ff fhde fheybd dfhey sd wyo gfj fggn cjvnf jcnjf fjncj fju djfu dcjndf  </p>
```