# Justify content with pre-wrap

Tags: css, firefox, word-wrap, justify

On Firefox, how can you justify text that has the `white-space: pre-wrap;` CSS attribute?

I need the `pre-wrap` to prevent the browser from collapsing whitespaces, but it breaks the `text-align: justify;` property. See http://jsfiddle.net/xpp48knq/ for example.

I would be ok with any solution that doesn't collapse spaces and that justifies content.

Comment: It's not intended to work at the moment:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#alignment-prop

Comment: That's sad. Do you have any idea of a workaround?

Comment: This seems to have what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30764631/3123195.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some workaround for ur problem.

U should remove 'white-space: pre-wrap' from the element, and replace all spaces in text to '​ '(mean zero-width space plus space). And everything will be working fine in every major browser.

Here's some example:
https://jsfiddle.net/gvm3x354/

```
<div id='output' class='text'>
</div>

.text {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}


var output = document.getElementById('output'),
  text = 'I\'m a justified  text with multiple    spaces between   words. Really cool,  so js. Found better workaround? E-mail me!';

text = text.replace(/\s/g, '&#8203; ');
output.innerHTML = text;
```